# How do I select a Wordpress page to act as a custom post type archive

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I have a custom post type that I would like to have the archive page be based on a page template. So that I would create a page using a template, and then assign that page to act a custom post type archive.
I see this being in done for WooCommerce where you select which pages are to be what section, or in buddy press.
but not sure how to go about it with general custom post types and archives.

Comment: If I got it right, [this might be what you're looking for](https://www.greengeeks.com/tutorials/convert-custom-post-types-wordpress/).

Comment: Not quite, but cool nonetheless. I have a document cpt with archive set to true.
I have a the archive-document.php file that that archive, and it will display a paginated list of all documents, which is as expected. But for my instance, I have a template using ACF that I would like to use to build out the page, and override the archive-document.php and instead serve the page I build with ACF.

I can create an option where I can set the page to be the "Document Archive" page. but I dont know how to make it so that if someone goes to 
example.com/documents , I get the custom built page.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways:

1.) If the page template already contains the custom loop which calls those CPTs, create an empty page in the WP backend and select your page template as its page template.

2.) Or rename your page template php file to "archive-xxxxx.php", where "xxxxx" should be replaced by your CPT name. (see also https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/ for details).

Answer (score 0):

What you can do better is set the archive to false and create a custom loop yourself. you can insert it via a shortcode (woocommerce used to do it this way too).

Comment: Although this creates issues with non-active menus if you need your slugs to be i.e /regions/ > /regions/region-name